# Custom analyzer with Neo4j's automatic indexing

Tags: neo4j

I know it's possible to specify a custom Lucene `Analyzer` when creating a Neo4j index like this:

```java
Index<Node> index= indexManager.forNodes("index", MapUtil.stringMap(
    IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene",
    "analyzer", MyAnalyzer.class.getName()
    ));
```

Is it possible to specify which Lucene `Analyzer` the automatic indexer should employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that no auto index exists in your db. You might use webadmin's index tab to get rid of them. Then restart the database and apply:

```
graphDb.index().forNodes("node_auto_index", MapUtil.stringMap( <your options go here> );
```

You can do the same with relationship's autoindex if required. The magic name here is `relationship_auto_index`.

Comment: Thanks! Can the same functionality be achieved in Neo4j 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible with the schema indexes in 2.0. However please file a issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new for having that feature.